# Trying to parse CSV file in Grails

Tags: csv, grails

I'm trying to parse a CSV file which has three fields.

My method looks like this:

```
// this action is called when the user submits the upload form
def handle() {
    CommonsMultipartFile file = request.getFile('filecsv')
    if(file.empty) {
        flash.error = g.message(code:'',default:'Empty cannot be uploaded')
    } else {
        InputStream fs = file.inputStream
        fs.splitEachLine(',') { row ->
            new Connection(
                    randomizedID: row[0],
                    token1: row[1],
                    token2: row[2]
            ).save(flush: true)

            key++

            println("Connection added")
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the output, the line "Connection added" is printed multiple times.
But when I go looking at my Connection list, there are none...

Comment: You might want to add `failOnError: true` to your `save()` so you can see if there is a validation error. Which is likely the problem. So `.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The problem appeared to be in the Connection controller, not in the parsing code.